# create reminder in sp foundation 2010

Tags: email, reminder

I would like to send `email` to specific users on every first day of the month.
So, I would like to send my first e-mail on 1.12., than second email 1.1.2016 etc. I started to write WF like this: pause until 1.12., than send email, than pause until 1.1.2016 an than send email, etc. Is there some other way or must I write every date until 1.12.2016?

Comment: for sending email **every first day of the month**, you can consider *Timer Job*